# Angular Mat-Slider Directives and Properties are not working

Tags: angular-material, angularjs-directive

I feel as if this should be straight forward but I cannot get Mat-Slider to work properly.  A slider does appear, and I can set the min, max and value of it.  However, I cannot get the range slider to work, that is the **input[matSliderStartThumb] input[matSliderEndThumb]** directives, nor the discrete or showTickMarks to work on my app.  I have copied the code directly from the example onto my app and still nothing.  Copied below is what the example is on the Angular-Material website and what I use on my app currently.

```
<mat-slider min="200" max="500" discrete>
  <input value="300" matSliderStartThumb>
  <input value="400" matSliderEndThumb>
</mat-slider>
```

And it just turns up like a normal slider.  Doesn't have 2 ranges and doesn't show the thumbnail.  This is really driving my head up a wall because it seems so straight forward.  Does anyone have any suggestions or tips ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Angular Material are you using? All the directives you mention were added in version 15.x, so if you're using an older version they will simply not be there and will not work.

Comment: @TotallyNewb ,  I did notice that my Angular Material was out of date, I performed an NG update @Angular/Material so it should be the latest version.  Are there dependencies like BrowserAnimations which need to be updated as well, or perhaps Angular itself as I am using version 13 of Angular ?

Comment: Angular Material's major version needs to be aligned with Angular major version. So if you want to use Material 15.x you should use Angular 15.x as well.

Comment: did you find answer